# Why is my coolant brown and overfilled?

Tags: coolant, subaru, overheating, impreza

I have a 2011 Subaru Impreza, and lately the engine overheat light has been turning on. I stopped driving it.

I took a look at the coolant reservoir today. It's full almost right to the top and it's thin and brown.

Is it possible that flushing it out and putting new coolant in will fix my overheating problem, or should I just take it straight to a shop?

Comment: Brown color is normally iron rust ; Do you have iron block or heads ? With an iron block it means the radiator cap is nor sealing- lets in air with each cool down which causes rust . Fix the problem ,then flush it.

Comment: Brown color? What kind of brown color? If it looks something like chocolate milk, you've got oil in your coolant, which is usually a blown head gasket or problem with an oil to water cooler. @blacksmith37 - It's a Subaru ... engine block and heads are aluminum.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 yea chocolate milk might be a good description. Could that explain why it's also overfilled?

Comment: Yes. If you put in oil without losing any coolant, the level is going to rise. Also tell you why you're overheating, which is probably what caused your issues in the first place ... wait ... chicken? egg? ... not sure.